# Slick grid set value on autocomplete cell

Tags: autocomplete, edit, slickgrid

I'm trying to set values in a slick grid from jQuery thru val and text e.g. .find('div.slick-cell.l2.r2').text('xyz'). There is a jquery autocomplete on the cell in question but it only gets activated on click. So when I click the cell in question it get overwritten by the initial defaultValue in the editor:

```
function ComboBoxEditor(args) {
    ...
    this.loadValue = function (item) {
        defaultValue = item[args.column.field] || "";
        $input.val(defaultValue);
        $input[0].defaultValue = defaultValue;
        $input.select();
    }; 
    ...
```

Can I get the jQuery text value from within the world of the slick grid.

Answer (score 0):

Think of slickgrid as a rendering engine and [dataView](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/DataView) as the data interface (You are using dataView right?) Jquery or javascript editing of dom elements isn't gong to work so think about how jquery/javascript can use the dataView methods to do the updating.
I ran into this same issue when adding [drag and drop of files](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) into [SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki)

I detect the elementID of the drop and map it back to the dataView row and column.

Here is the function I used for text pasting:

```
function insertText(textString, location) {
            grid.resetActiveCell();
            $(location).click();
            var startCell = grid.getActiveCell();
            if (startCell) {
// only paste text into active cells for now
                    var columnDef   =       grid.getColumns();
                    var colField = columnDef[startCell.cell].field;
                    if (!dataView.getItem(startCell.row)) {
// new row
                            var tobj = {'id': "new_" + (Math.random() + 1).toString(36).substring(7)};
                            tobj[colField] = textString;
                            dataView.addItem(tobj);
                    } else {
// modify existing cell
                            var item = dataView.getItem(startCell.row);
                            item[colField] = textString;
                            dataView.updateItem(item.id, item);

                    }
                    grid.resetActiveCell();
                    grid.render();
                    dataView.refresh();
    }
}
```